# Database connects fine, phpmyadmin won't work

Tags: phpmyadmin, localhost, wamp

I have been able to connect to my local database just fine; running queries from mysql command line works just fine, it's when I try to navigate to phpmyadmin that it gives me the following error:

```
    Error

    MySQL said: Documentation
    #2002 - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

    The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured).
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix this, I tried searching other places and I just don't get it.

Answer (score 0):

If phpmyadmin is on the same machine as the DB, then it can connect to the socket or via TCP. While I dont know, since you didn't post any of your config, it would appear that might be using TCP and that it is pointed at an address, or localhost, or 127.0.0.1, or x.x.x.x, or a port number, that is not open, or listening, or is firewalled. (It is a long shot, but check the hostname in  your conf file against the output from **cat /etc/hosts** to see if those point to the same location or IP.) If you post your config', I could tell you in a minute. If you want to run **netstat -tupl** or **netstat -an | grep -i sql** and see if your daemon is listening on the expected IP & port, that will give us a clue. Depending on your machine, you can also trying doing an **updatedb** followed by a "locate mysql | grep -i sock" to see where your mysql socket is located. Compare the results from these couple tests against your config'. Let me know. Cheers. Jason *Post Script: next time you post, please include OS, versions, editions, locations, etc, so we can help you better.*